# How to set default values in openldap?

Tags: ldap

How can we set the default value for an attribute in openldap like we do in mysql schema?

**MYSQL**

```
 create table test (str varchar(32), ts TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In LDAP you can't.

[RFC 2252](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2252.txt) which is AFAIK still leading with regards to LDAP attribute syntax definitions does not provide for default values.

An ObjectClass definition can only require that certain attributes must be present and some are optional, but not a default value.

Answer (score 2):

That's simple: You can't. LDAP schemas doesn't offer this feature.